# How to customize ScrollView from qtquick controls 2.3

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using using ScrollView control from `import QtQuick.Controls 2.3`version because it looks better that prior ones.

The problem is that if i try to customize it with `ScrollBar.vertical` it looses some functionality. I can't press it and drag it up and down like it does by default.

I've searched and i've find a way to do the drag functionality.

The code i've used is:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    height: 200
    width: 400
    ListModel {
        id: libraryModel
        ListElement {
            text: "A Masterpiece"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "Brilliance"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "Outstanding"
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        width:parent.width
        height: parent.height
        ScrollView {
            id:scrollView
            anchors.fill:parent
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                parent: scrollView
                x: scrollView.mirrored ? 0 : scrollView.width - width
                y: scrollView.topPadding
                height: scrollView.availableHeight
                active: scrollView.ScrollBar.horizontal.active
                contentItem: Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 6
                    implicitHeight: 100
                    radius: width/2
                    color: scrollView.pressed ? "orange" : "green"
                }
            }
            Column{
                width:parent.width
                spacing:10
                TextField {
                    id:textField
                    implicitHeight: 30
                    font.bold: true
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id:comboBox
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    textRole: "text"
                    model: libraryModel
                }
                TextField {
                    id:textField2
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    implicitHeight: 30
                    font.bold: true
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id:comboBox2
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    textRole: "text"
                    model: libraryModel
                }
                TextField {
                    id:textField3
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    implicitHeight: 30
                    font.bold: true
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id:comboBox3
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    textRole: "text"
                    model: libraryModel
                }
                TextField {
                    id:textField4
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    implicitHeight: 30
                    font.bold: true
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id:comboBox4
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    textRole: "text"
                    model: libraryModel
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What did i missed on the code? Maybe on `ScrollBar`?

Comment: Are you sure you can drag scrollbars with non-customized item? I see the [ScrollBar](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/5.12/src/imports/controls/ScrollBar.qml#L53) has no `MouseArea`  or whatever that you could control it by mouse.

Comment: @folibis if i remove the property ```ScrollBar.vertical``` and i try to drag de scroll it works.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it by setting a different parent for ScrollBar ([link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#attaching-scrollbar-to-a-flickable)). Also, to change the color you need to check `ScrollBar` property instead of `ScrollView`:

```
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            id: scrollBar
            parent: scrollView.parent
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            x: scrollView.mirrored ? 0 : scrollView.width - width
            y: scrollView.topPadding
            height: scrollView.availableHeight
            active: scrollView.ScrollBar.horizontal.active
            contentItem: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 6
                implicitHeight: 100
                radius: width/2
                color: scrollBar.pressed ? "orange" : "green"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `z: 1` (or any value > 0) to your `ScrollBar` the problem should be fixed.

I am not sure about the reason but it looks like it is related to the scrollbar attached by default to the `ScrollView`, that prevents you to access the custom scrollbar in this 10px zone.

cf [Why is there a dead zone on the right side of my flipable?](https://forum.qt.io/topic/90315/why-is-there-a-dead-zone-on-the-right-side-of-my-flipable)